# Scalable, Centered Image Link

Tags: html, css, image

I'm using HTML & CSS to try to make a centered image, that when you click it, it gives you the full size version. The image is also scalable so on smaller devices it scales down. Right now I am not worrying about bandwidth of the client. I'm having an issue where the clickable area is outside of the image which makes it look like theres some sort of invisible link.

Here is what I mean.[image: problem image]

All areas where I have arrows the user can click - but that doesn't make sense. I just want the image to be clickable. I can get it to work, but I have to use inline block on the a tag, which ruins the scaling depending on the width of the screen.

Here is the HTML for this part.

```
<a class="image_link" href="/images/guides/wavelist_editing/fullsize/wave3.jpg"><img class="scalable_image popout_image centered" src="/images/guides/wavelist_editing/wave3.jpg"></a>
```

And the CSS.

```
.content a:link.image_link { /*Not overqualified - overrides stuff on main.css. gets rid of the underline*/
    border-bottom: 0px none transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
}

.content .popout_image {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 10px #555;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100px;
}

.content .scalable_image {
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

To verify this information here is the computed values for the link and image respectively in firefox (the first image incorrectly shows inline-block, I took this image in testing, it's actually block - but both values introduce an error, no-scaling or too big for clicking):
[image: link stats]
[image: img stats]

I feel like I am missing something really obvious here. I can't google this because "image link" seems to be pretty generic.

Comment: Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/drLd534s/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve it like this:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pzmkm1o6/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content">
    <a class="image_link" href="/images/guides/wavelist_editing/fullsize/wave3.jpg"><img class="scalable_image popout_image centered" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
<div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.content {
    text-align: center; /* add this */
}
.content a:link.image_link {
    border-bottom: 0px none transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block; /* add this */
}
.content .popout_image {
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 10px #555;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100px;
}
.content .scalable_image {
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9;
}
```

Comment: Had to add a lot of new alignment code to the other items in my CSS, but it's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
</a>

a {display:inline-block;width:80%; height:auto}

img {width:100%}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ko2wzah9/

Comment: The parent of the image cannot be inline-block. It must be block or the image cannot scale down because it has no relative parent size. Weird standards thing.

Comment: @Mgamerz then I'm not sure I completely understand the issue.. you need the image to scale but not the clickable area?

Comment: The clickable area should be the same as the image. Essentially the image is the link, but not the areas to the left or right if I have a max size. Edit: Checking the jsfiddle seems to show that it works like I would want. Let me implement it and check. Final edit: This does not center the image.

Answer (score 0):

As  I understand, you need like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>image link</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <a href="http://lorempixel.com/700/700" class="image-link">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300" alt="">
      </a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and the css

```
a{
  display: inline-block;
  position: static;
}

a img{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

a:before{
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(031, 031, 031, 0.7);
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

[the example](http://jsfiddle.net/t61b44bm/1/)

Comment: Maybe I am just really bad at explaining it, but Mary's comment was exactly what I wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/drLd534s/